# Printing text from a specific html tag, with only the tags class name. PYTHON3

Tags: html, python-3.x

I need a code "snippet" (or what you call them) that prints out all of the words inside a specific html class, not tag but class.

`<h1 class="example">Hello people!</h1>`

Lets say for some reason the HTML of a website only looked like that, I would need a code that could print out whats inside the H1 TAG but only with the class. I have tried researching this but havent gotten anything that would have helped (although I am bad at researching).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) can do this for you

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
html_doc = '<h1 class="example">Hello people!</h1>'
# or, if you need to get the content from an http endpoint
# html_doc = requests.get(url_to_source).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
for heading in soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "example"}):
    print(heading.string)
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats almost exactly what I want, but it seems that Beautiful Soup is not fitted for a HTTP Client. Simply, I would need it to take some random class from a random website example. https://www.html.am/templates/downloads/bryantsmith/greenblade/ . How should I go about to make Requests feed it to Beautiful Soup?